# Flutter doctor --android-licenses stuck at some point

Tags: android, flutter, powershell, installation

So ive been trying to install flutter into my laptop. When i was in the process of installing flutter, using this command line **flutter doctor --android-licenses** does not give me the exact correct process that i need.

Instead of showing 7 out of 7 licenses it only shows 6 out of 7 hence making the process stuck at some point. Does any one know the reason for this issue ?

[image: Powershell Image]

Comment: use a vpn and see if it works?

Comment: Omg, it actually allowed me to type in y/N after i opened my VPN.

Comment: For whomever is voting to close this as general computing, please [read the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) carefully: "software tools commonly used by programmers" are on-topic.  Questions about using software are only off-topic if they do not "directly involve tools used primarily for programming."

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is the problem but when i tried the recommendation by @Benyamin to open VPN and all of the sudden everything just works like a charm. Thank you once again.